# Build error on substrate-node-template

Tags: substrate-node-template, rust

I'm met with an error when running this command `cargo build --release` on [substrate-note-template](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template).

I haven't really done anything other than `git clone` to my directory and executed the cargo build mentioned above.

```
error: failed to run custom build command for `tikv-jemalloc-sys v0.5.2+5.3.0-patched`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/mnt/c/Users/name/Desktop/Github/metaschool/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/tikv-jemalloc-sys-166d53d735a1d9b3/build-script-build` (exit status: 101)
  --- stdout
  TARGET=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  HOST=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  NUM_JOBS=8
  OUT_DIR="/mnt/c/Users/name/Desktop/Github/metaschool/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/tikv-jemalloc-sys-10b36ab64da2ffdc/out"
  BUILD_DIR="/mnt/c/Users/name/Desktop/Github/metaschool/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/tikv-jemalloc-sys-10b36ab64da2ffdc/out/build"
  SRC_DIR="/root/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/tikv-jemalloc-sys-0.5.2+5.3.0-patched"
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=JEMALLOC_OVERRIDE
  OPT_LEVEL = Some("3")
  TARGET = Some("x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu")
  HOST = Some("x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu")
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CC_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  CC_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CC_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  CC_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_CC
  HOST_CC = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CC
  CC = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CFLAGS_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  CFLAGS_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CFLAGS_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  CFLAGS_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_CFLAGS
  HOST_CFLAGS = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CFLAGS
  CFLAGS = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS
  CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
  DEBUG = Some("false")
  CARGO_CFG_TARGET_FEATURE = Some("fxsr,sse,sse2")
  CC="cc"
  CFLAGS="-O3 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fPIC -m64 -Wall"
  JEMALLOC_REPO_DIR="jemalloc"
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=JEMALLOC_SYS_WITH_MALLOC_CONF
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=JEMALLOC_SYS_WITH_LG_PAGE
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=JEMALLOC_SYS_WITH_LG_HUGEPAGE
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=JEMALLOC_SYS_WITH_LG_QUANTUM
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=JEMALLOC_SYS_WITH_LG_VADDR
  running: "sh" "/mnt/c/Users/name/Desktop/Github/metaschool/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/tikv-jemalloc-sys-10b36ab64da2ffdc/out/build/configure" "--disable-cxx" "--enable-doc=no" "--enable-shared=no" "--with-private-namespace=_rjem_" "--host=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu" "--build=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu" "--prefix=/mnt/c/Users/name/Desktop/Github/metaschool/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/tikv-jemalloc-sys-10b36ab64da2ffdc/out"
  running: "tail" "-n" "100" "/mnt/c/Users/name/Desktop/Github/metaschool/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/tikv-jemalloc-sys-10b36ab64da2ffdc/out/build/config.log"
  XSLROOT=''
  XSLTPROC=''
  a=''
  abi=''
  abs_objroot='/mnt/c/Users/name/Desktop/Github/metaschool/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/tikv-jemalloc-sys-10b36ab64da2ffdc/out/build/'
  abs_srcroot='/mnt/c/Users/name/Desktop/Github/metaschool/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/tikv-jemalloc-sys-10b36ab64da2ffdc/out/build/'
  ac_ct_CC=''
  ac_ct_CXX=''
  bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
  build='x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
  build_alias='x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
  build_cpu=''
  build_os=''
  build_vendor=''
  cfghdrs_in=''
  cfghdrs_out=''
  cfgoutputs_in=''
  cfgoutputs_out=''
  datadir='${datarootdir}'
  datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
  docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE}'
  dvidir='${docdir}'
  enable_autogen=''
  enable_cache_oblivious=''
  enable_cxx='no'
  enable_debug=''
  enable_doc='no'
  enable_experimental_smallocx=''
  enable_fill=''
  enable_initial_exec_tls=''
  enable_lazy_lock=''
  enable_log=''
  enable_opt_safety_checks=''
  enable_opt_size_checks=''
  enable_prof=''
  enable_readlinkat=''
  enable_shared='no'
  enable_static=''
  enable_stats=''
  enable_tls=''
  enable_uaf_detection=''
  enable_utrace=''
  enable_xmalloc=''
  enable_zone_allocator=''
  exe=''
  exec_prefix='NONE'
  host='x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
  host_alias='x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
  host_cpu=''
  host_os=''
  host_vendor=''
  htmldir='${docdir}'
  importlib=''
  includedir='${prefix}/include'
  infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
  install_suffix=''
  je_=''
  jemalloc_version=''
  jemalloc_version_bugfix=''
  jemalloc_version_gid=''
  jemalloc_version_major=''
  jemalloc_version_minor=''
  jemalloc_version_nrev=''
  libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
  libdl=''
  libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
  libprefix=''
  link_whole_archive=''
  localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
  localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
  mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
  o=''
  objroot=''
  oldincludedir='/usr/include'
  pdfdir='${docdir}'
  prefix='/mnt/c/Users/name/Desktop/Github/metaschool/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/tikv-jemalloc-sys-10b36ab64da2ffdc/out'
  private_namespace=''
  program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
  psdir='${docdir}'
  rev='2'
  sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
  sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
  so=''
  srcroot=''
  sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
  target_alias=''
  /* confdefs.h */
  #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
  #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
  #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
  #define PACKAGE_STRING ""
  #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
  #define PACKAGE_URL ""

  configure: exit 1

  --- stderr
  configure: error: Prefix should not contain spaces
  thread 'main' panicked at 'command did not execute successfully: "sh" "/mnt/c/Users/name/Desktop/Github/metaschool/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/tikv-jemalloc-sys-10b36ab64da2ffdc/out/build/configure" "--disable-cxx" "--enable-doc=no" "--enable-shared=no" "--with-private-namespace=_rjem_" "--host=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu" "--build=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu" "--prefix=/mnt/c/Users/name/Desktop/Github/metaschool/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/tikv-jemalloc-sys-10b36ab64da2ffdc/out"
  expected success, got: exit status: 1', /root/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/tikv-jemalloc-sys-0.5.2+5.3.0-patched/build.rs:330:9
  note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
```

I have no idea what to provide to help giving this issue a context so I'll just list down what I'm using

Editor: VS Code

OS: Windows 10

rust config:

[image: toolchains]

wsl: wsl version 2

Answer (score 1):

From this line:

```
  configure: error: Prefix should not contain spaces
```

I guess, there are some spaces in your username?